# Problem with nodemailer sending to outlook

Tags: outlook, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I experienced some problem using nodemailer with Amazon SES.

I set up a node backend using nodemailer for sending mails. Everything is working fine when sending to gmail adresses. But for some reason it's not working for outlook adresses. (outlook, live, hotmail).

I'm using Amazon ses (workmail) to send the emails. Here's my configurations :

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.mail.eu-west-1.awsapps.com",
        port: 465,
        name: "mydomain.com", //Replaced with my actual domain name
        secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
          user: 'my emeail adress',
          pass: 'my password'
        },
      });


const data = await ejs.renderFile(__dirname + '/html/CodeTemplate.ejs', { code: code })

      let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"MyName" <Myemailadress>', // sender address
        to: receiveremailadress, // list of receivers
        subject: "test", // Subject line
        text: "", // plain text body
        html: data
      });
```

As it's working fine with other adresses, they receive my emails using nodemailer, I don't understand why it's not working with outlook adresses, I also tried to send directly from the amazon email adress (on the workmail) and it doesn't works either to outlook adress. Altough the emails are in the sent box, the receiver don't receive it. And it's not in the spam box.

What am I missing ?

Thanks a lot for the help